# MSBuild "Debug" configuration not working in VS 2010 Beta 2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm trying to set up my environment for developing, debugging and deploying Windows Desktop Gadgets.  I've hit a bit of a roadblock in my project, where I can't run a build on my gadget when the configuration is set to "Debug".  If the configuration is set to "Release", the build goes through the following custom tasks:

1. Copy gadget contents to a seperate folder.
2. Minify/obfuscate the javascript files, removing comments and whitespace.
3. Package the files into a CAB file.
4. Sign the CAB file with a digital certificate.

This runs just fine, my "Debug" configuration has the following tasks defined

1. Copy gadget folder to `AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets\`.
2. Start the gadget using the IDesktopGadget interface.

If I copy those two tasks to the "Release" configuration, they run just fine - no problems whatsoever.  I've tried creating a seperate configuration called "Test", copied from the "Release" configuration.

If I try to build any configuration other than "Release", I get an instant message saying "Build succeeded" but no tasks have run at all.

**EDIT:** I've started a bounty because I still have the same problem with VS 2010 RC and it's very frustrating.

**FURTHER EDIT:**
Thanks to John I was able to debug the build process.  It led me to realize that the `<Target>` element with condition for debugging was being completely ignored (not even processed).  When I swapped the position of my `<Target>` elements, it worked:

```
<Target Name="Build" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <!--
      <Obfuscate PathToJasob="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jasob.com\Jasob 3.5" Path="$(GadgetFolder)" Output="$(GadgetName)_obf" log="jasob_log.txt" />
  -->
  <BuildGadget BuildFormat="CAB" Path="$(GadgetFolder)" Target="$(GadgetName).gadget" />
  <SignGadget CertName="Cert1" TimestampURL="http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode" Target="$(GadgetName).gadget" />
</Target>
<Target Name="Build" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
  <CopyToGadgets GadgetFolder="$(GadgetFolder)" GadgetName="$(GadgetName)" />
  <RunGadget GadgetName="$(GadgetName)" />
</Target>
```

So it looks like the second `<Target Name="Build">` element overrides the first, despite the `Condition` attribute being present.  What can I do?

Comment: What is the build output when you do diagnostic logging?  (Pass `/verbosity:diag` as a flag to the msbuild command line)

Comment: Have you deleted all previously created dll- and pdb-files before you run the debug build, just to be sure, that msbuild does not think they are up-to-date? Have you deleted these files also from your shadow copy cache (somewhere in "c:\documents and settings\<user>\local settings\")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joe suggests:

Change your output path like this, and see if that fixes the issue:

```
<OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
```

**Update**

Have you tried running `msbuild /verbosity:diagnostic` ?

Can you try that and show the output?

**Second Update**

Make one target 'build', and then make two tasks in that target:

```
<Target Name="Build">
    <CallTarget Targets="BuildRelease" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'" />
    <CallTarget Targets="BuildDebug" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />
</Target>

<Target Name="BuildRelease">
    <!--
        <Obfuscate PathToJasob="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jasob.com\Jasob 3.5" Path="$(GadgetFolder)" Output="$(GadgetName)_obf" log="jasob_log.txt" />
    -->
    <BuildGadget BuildFormat="CAB" Path="$(GadgetFolder)" Target="$(GadgetName).gadget" />
    <SignGadget CertName="Cert1" TimestampURL="http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode" Target="$(GadgetName).gadget" />
</Target>

<Target Name="BuildDebug">
  <CopyToGadgets GadgetFolder="$(GadgetFolder)" GadgetName="$(GadgetName)" />
  <RunGadget GadgetName="$(GadgetName)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: As I said in my comment reply to Joe, I had already tried this.  In fact, the reason it was set to `bin\Release\` in the first place was due to me copying the Release configuration in an attempt to get it working.

Comment: Thanks, your reply to Joe wasn't as clear.  This clarifies it.

Comment: @John: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of debugging.  I'm pretty new to using VS so I wasn't aware you could do this.  I've discovered what the problem is and edited it into my question.  Do you have any further ideas?  Thanks again :-)

Comment: @Andy E - Names for the targets need to be unique, so the msbuild parser is probably just dropping the second target named 'Build'.

Make 2 targets specific to debug or release, and then update your build target to call either one conditionally on the build type.

Comment: @John: Can't thank you enough for your help, it worked perfectly.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess:

Your Debug build has its output path set to `bin\Release\`.
The timestamps of the files in `bin\Release\` are probably causing MSBuild to conclude that the debug build is already up to date. Try changing the the output path to `bin\Debug\` for debug builds.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer even if it was just a guess.  Alas, this wasn't the case until I copied the "Release" configuration to the "Debug" configuration in order to try and get it working.  I will still change it back, however.